# External monitor not recognised on Macbook Late 2016 with Usb-C to Thunderbolt 2 adapter

Tags: macos, display, macbook, thunderbolt, usb-c

I have an external monitor that I can connect to using my existing macbook via thunderbolt 2. I am using an Thunderbolt 2 to Displayport cable. Now that I have new macbook (late 2016) I also bought the apple usb-c to thunderbolt 2 adapter. But my external display is not recognised by macbook through adapter and cable. How can I use my monitor?

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like apple's usb-c to thunderbolt 2 adapter does not support displays using mini display port.
It is mentioned here clearly and the guy on twitter complains for the exact same problem;
https://9to5mac.com/2016/11/17/apple-macbook-pro-thunderbolt-3-adapter-displayport/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I first bought the Apple dongle, and started to troubleshoot things like the DisplayPort cable since it was not working. I then realised that the Apple dongle actually are a Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 dongle, and that Thunderbolt 2 and Mini DisplayPort is not the same thing.

I ordered an 3rd party dongle, Kanex USB-C to DisplayPort Adapter, which works perfectly.

Comment: How does your answer provide a solution to OP

Comment: He asks "How can I use my monitor?". I answer "buy an 3rd party dongle", and give an example of one I know work. How does it not provide a solution?